# R function returning no value

Tags: r, function

```
x <- c(2.2, 7.8, -4.4, 0.0, -1.2, 3.9, 4.9, 2.0, -5.7, -7.9, -4.9,  28.7,  4.9)

quartiles<-function(x){
bound<-quantile(x)
MED<-median(x)
k<-c(). #put values of x less than median in vector K
S<-c(). #put values of x larger than median in vector S

for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if (x[i]<MED){
K<-x[i]}
else{S<-x[i]
}
i<i+1
}
  iqr1<-c(median(k)-median(S)) #calculate interquartile for x
return(list(bound[2],bound[4], iqr1))  
}
```

I would like to get the value in return for `iqr1` but I am getting:

> quartiles(x) [[1]]  25%
> -4.4
>
> [[2]] 75%
> 4.9
>
> [[3]] numeric(0)

Comment: I know there are two solutions below but can you describe in words what you would like as the output and what you want the function to do? I feel like there is a way to simply this.

Comment: definitely. `IQR(x)` is the simplest for the numerical solution, but I remember solving all sorts of problems that already had solutions early in my learning process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer helps but isn't quite correct yet.
One issue is that in your code, you're overwriting your `k` and `S` variables, not making a vector.
Another is that you always add the median to `S` which gives you different types of IQR calculations depending on whether you have an even or odd number of items in your vector of numbers (`x`) and whether the median is in the vector or not.

This version addresses the coding issues, but not the statistical issues of how to calculate the IQR consistently.

```
quartiles <- function(x){
  bound <- quantile(x)
  MED <- median(x)
  k <- vector(mode="numeric") # empty vector for values of x less than median 
  S <- vector(mode="numeric") # empty vector for values of x larger than or equal to median 
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(x[i]<MED){
      k <- append(k, x[i]) # append or add values to k
      }
    else if(x[i]>MED){
      S <- append(S, x[i]) # append or add values to S
      }
  }
  iqr1 <- c(median(S)-median(k)) # calculate interquartile range for x
  ## prints can be commented out once you know things are working 
  print(sort(k)) # sorted vector of values of x less than median
  print(median(k))
  print(sort(S)) # sorted vector of values of x larger than or equal to median
  print(median(S))
  print(iqr1)
  return(list(bound[2],bound[4], iqr1))  
  }
```

now to test it,

```
qx <- quartiles(x)
```

produces (due to the print statements):

```
[1] -7.9 -5.7 -4.9 -4.4 -1.2  0.0
[1] -4.65
[1]  2.2  3.9  4.9  4.9  7.8 28.7
[1] 4.9
[1] 9.55
```

and `qx` shows the returned object:

```
[[1]]
 25% 
-4.4 
[[2]]
75% 
4.9 
[[3]]
[1] 9.55
```

for comparison, using the functions in R:

```
> quantile(x)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
-7.9 -4.4  2.0  4.9 28.7
```

which matches, but the IQR...

```
> IQR(x, type=7)
[1] 9.3
```

```
> IQR(x, type=6)
[1] 9.55
```

```
> IQR(x, type=5)
[1] 9.425
```

matches `type=6` in this case, but what about another test case?

```
a <- c(1.1, 2.2, 7.8, -4.4, 0.0, -1.2, 3.9, 4.9, 2.0, -5.7, -7.9, -4.9,  28.7,  4.9)
```

```
> qa <- quartiles(a)
[1] -7.9 -5.7 -4.9 -4.4 -1.2  0.0  1.1
[1] -4.4
[1]  2.0  2.2  3.9  4.9  4.9  7.8 28.7
[1] 4.9
[1] 9.3
```

```
> qa
[[1]]
 25% 
-3.6 
[[2]]
 75% 
4.65 
[[3]]
[1] 9.3
```

```
> quantile(a)
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
-7.90 -3.60  1.55  4.65 28.70
```

```
> IQR(a, type=7)
[1] 8.25
```

```
> IQR(a, type=6)
[1] 9.425
```

```
> IQR(a, type=5)
[1] 9.3
```

so you get different types of IQR depending on the list...

Comment: Thank you so much for a thorough explanation. It helped me to learn a lot. Now if I would like to use the quartile function that I have but returns a vector. and use it in another function in order to get the boolean True or false as a vector how can I do it.

Comment: I have my function below but the output is not correct. F<-function(x){ Q<-quartiles(x) min_outlier<-Q[1]-1.5*Q[3] #outlier based on 25% quartiles min_outlier max_outlier<-Q[2]+1.5*Q[3] #outlier based on 75% quartiles max_outlier x<c() for (i in 1:length(x)){ if (max_outlier< x[i] || min_outlier>x[i]) {x[i]<-print("true")} else{x[i]<-print("false")} i<-i+1 } boolean<-c(n) return(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like small syntax errors. Just remove the `.` from `k<-c().` and `S<-c().` as well as use the correct `K` in your calculations. It's recommended to not differentiate variables solely by letter case.

```
x <- c(2.2, 7.8, -4.4, 0.0, -1.2, 3.9, 4.9, 2.0, -5.7, -7.9, -4.9,  28.7,  4.9)

quartiles<-function(x){
    bound<-quantile(x)
    MED<-median(x)
    k<-c() #put values of x less than median in vector K
    S<-c()#put values of x larger than median in vector S
    
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
        if (x[i]<MED){
            K<-x[i]}
        else{S<-x[i]
        }
        i<i+1
    }
    iqr1<-c(median(K)-median(S)) #calculate interquartile for x
    return(list(bound[2],bound[4], iqr1))  
}
```

```
quartiles(x)

[[1]]
 25% 
-4.4 

[[2]]
75% 
4.9 

[[3]]
[1] -9.8
```

To return a vector just use `return(c(bound[2],bound[4], iqr1))` instead of `return(list(bound[2],bound[4], iqr1))`

```
x <- c(2.2, 7.8, -4.4, 0.0, -1.2, 3.9, 4.9, 2.0, -5.7, -7.9, -4.9,  28.7,  4.9)

quartiles<-function(x){
    bound<-quantile(x)
    MED<-median(x)
    k<-c() #put values of x less than median in vector K
    S<-c()#put values of x larger than median in vector S
    
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
        if (x[i]<MED){
            K<-x[i]}
        else{S<-x[i]
        }
        i<i+1
    }
    iqr1<-c(median(K)-median(S)) #calculate interquartile for x
    return(c(bound[2],bound[4], iqr1))  
}
```

```
 quartiles(x)
 25%  75%      
-4.4  4.9 -9.8
```

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept this answer if you think it clearly answered your question (click the checkmark next to my answer)!

Comment: If I would like to return a vector instead of list what do I need to do?

Comment: This code is incorrect, try this `quartiles(sort(x))` shouldn't change anything, but it does. Also the subtraction in `iqr1`is backwards.

Comment: F<-function(x){
  Q<-quartiles(x)
  min_outlier<-Q[1]-1.5*Q[3]  #outlier based on 25% quartiles 
  min_outlier
  max_outlier<-Q[2]+1.5*Q[3] #outlier based on 75% quartiles
  max_outlier
  x<-vector()
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (max_outlier< x[i] || min_outlier>x[i]) {x[i]<-print("true")}
     else{x[i]<-print("false")}
    x<-append(x, x[i])
  i<-i+1
    }
  return(c(x))
}
  
 F(x) 

the output should be a vector of true or false
Error in if (max_outlier < x[i] || min_outlier > x[i]) { : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
Any idea how to correct my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So unless you need a function to do what you want- you can achieve your desired results in a few lines of code without a for loop or a function. You can utilize which to split the vector by the median and take the median of the lower and upper splits and take the difference.

```
x <- c(2.2, 7.8, -4.4, 0.0, -1.2, 3.9, 4.9, 2.0, -5.7, -7.9, -4.9,  28.7,  4.9)


y <- median(x[which(x>=median(x))])

z <- median(x[which(x<median(x))])

aa <- y-z

bb <- c(z,y,aa)

names(bb) <- c("25%", "75%", "Your IQR")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a thorough explanation.  It helped me to learn a lot.  Now if I would like to use the quartile function that I have but returns a vector.  and use it in another function in order to get the boolean True or false as a vector how can I do it.

Comment: I have my function below but the output is not correct. F<-function(x){
  Q<-quartiles(x)
  min_outlier<-Q[1]-1.5*Q[3]  #outlier based on 25% quartiles 
  min_outlier
  max_outlier<-Q[2]+1.5*Q[3] #outlier based on 75% quartiles
  max_outlier
  x<c()
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (max_outlier< x[i] || min_outlier>x[i]) {x[i]<-print("true")}
     else{x[i]<-print("false")}
  i<-i+1
    }
   boolean<-c(n)
  return(boolean)
}

Comment: @Mary it seems your second comment is a second question. I would either edit the current question and put that code in there or post another question on SO